# Java Split Date Value returned from DB to into separte date and time String

Tags: java, sql, string, datetime, date

I am reading a date column from the Oracle DB.

The column type is `Date`.

Example Date data is: 2011-12-06 14:28:12

Now when I am reading this date I want to split the date part into a separate String and Time part into another.

// here's the code I am working with.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); 

// some loop.
    SomeBean bean =  new SomeBean();
    Date date  = convertTimestamp(rs.getTimestamp("DATE_VAL"));
    bean.setTime(date==null?"":convertToTimeStamp(date,true));
    bean.setDate(date==null?"": df.format(date));           
// end some loop.

private java.util.Date convertTimestamp(java.sql.Timestamp timestamp) {
    if (timestamp == null)
        return null;
    else
        return new java.util.Date(timestamp.getTime());
}

private  String convertToTimeStamp(Date date, boolean showSeconds) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    return convertToTimeStamp(c, showSeconds);
}   

public static String convertToTimeStamp(Calendar time, boolean showSeconds) {
    String hours = Integer.toString(time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    if (hours.length() == 1) {
        hours = '0' + hours;
    }
    String minutes = Integer.toString(time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    if (minutes.length() == 1) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }
    if (showSeconds) {
        String seconds = Integer.toString(time.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        if (seconds.length() == 1) {
            seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else {
        return hours + ":" + minutes;
    }
}
```

Please help. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the current problem with the code you've shown here?

Comment: @ MДΓΓ БДLL The return date and time Strings populated are empty. Although the column has the date value specified in the question. The date column format wont change.

Comment: Why not just use two different `DateFormat` instances - one for the date, and one for the time? Even better - consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I would rather fix what I am working with rather using a new library at this time. Can you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I would recommend to have a look at [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/): it has a lot of easy going date and time functions. (a lot easier than the java date).

converting java.sql.Date to joda DateTime I use:

```
public static DateTime convertSqlDateToDateTime(java.sql.Date sqlDate){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(sqlDate);
    //note: java months are between 0 and 11:
    DateTime dt=new DateTime(c.get(Calendar.YEAR),c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),c.get(Calendar.SECOND),c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    return dt;
}
```

This will at least save you one function, and will maybe help you to your solution.

To convert a java.sql.TimeStamp to joda DateTime:

```
public static DateTime convertSqlTimeStampToDateTime(java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(sqlTimestamp);
    //note: java months are between 0 and 11:
    DateTime dt=new DateTime(c.get(Calendar.YEAR),c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),c.get(Calendar.SECOND),c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    return dt;
}
```

Second of all, why not use the DateFormatter to convert your date to a string you want?

Sticking to the Joda DateTime, use:

```
/**
 * Converts a DateTime to a string using the given pattern (format)
 * @param dateTime
 * @param pattern
 * @return
 */
public static String convertDateTimeToPattern(DateTime dateTime,String pattern){
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
    return dateTime.toString(fmt);
}
```

U can use the same formats as the java.Date and Time formatters:

pattern = "DD-MM-YYYY" (dutch notation) or "YYYY-MM-DD" (uk notation) and for time pattern="hh:mm:ss"

if you want to stick to your method, create another SimpleDateFormat, and use this last pattern ("hh:mm:ss") to create a time String.

Please, at leaste change this function:

> public static String convertToTimeStamp(Calendar time, boolean
>   showSeconds)

in to:

```
public static String convertToTimeStamp(Date date, boolean showSeconds) {
    String pattern = "hh:mm:ss";
    if (!showSeconds) {
        pattern = "hh:mm";
    }
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    return df.format(date);
}
```

In your last remark, i gues you asked for:

```
public static String convertToDateString(Date date) {
    String pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD"; 
    //(or another date format, like in dutch: "DD-MM-YYY"
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    return df.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer. I can't use joda library at the moment. How can I modify my code using Standard Java api to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Ok, i just read your comment on Joda DateTime, I understand you do not want to try a new library. But please look also at my last edit :)

Comment: Thanks. you were missing new keyword in the last method. What about the date String now. I mean time should be ok. How would i modify to get the just the date part? Please reply. Thanks

Comment: as I suggested, using the date pattern in the end of my answer, but I can edit it to give you this function as well (not tested though)

Comment: sorry about the new keyword, as I said, not tested: typing the code in here (unfortunately no java edit mode in stackoverflow edit :) )

Comment: Thank you so much to you and to other you answered this question.

Answer (score 1):

Besides some questionable quality of code, your main problem is these conditions **reversed**

```
bean.setTime(date!=null?"":convertToTimeStamp(date,true));                       
bean.setDate(date!=null?"": df.format(date));
```

**should be replaced with:**

```
bean.setTime(date==null?"":convertToTimeStamp(date,true));                       
bean.setDate(date==null?"": df.format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pin pointing the potential bug. Fixed. Thanks agian.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `SimpleDateFormat` objects, one that parses the `Date` portion and one that parses the `Time` portion, you can get each of these portions with `String.split()` on the SPACE character.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
    DateFormat formatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date now = new Date();

    System.out.println("dateOnly: " + formatDate.format(now));
    System.out.println("timeOnly: " + formatTime.format(now));
```